# Did I write this logic expression correctly?

Tags: logic

[image: The ciruit]

This is what I came up with.
$$Y=A+AB+B+C'+B+C'D+D$$
Is it safe to say that it is correct or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer can't be right because it depends on $D$. Note the following:

- If $D$ is on, then the NOR gate it feeds into is off;
- If $D$ is off, then the NAND gate it feeds into is on, so the NOR gate is off again.

So we can actually eliminate the NOR gate completely from the circuit without having any effect.

Then the expression is much simpler to analyse:

- If $A$ is on, then $Y$ is on.
- If $A$ is off, then the AND gate it feeds into is off, so the circuit reduces to "$B$ or not $C$".

So a simplified expression is $Y = A + B + C'$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i need a not simplified expression of this circuit. I need the expression to it as it is, i am not sure if what i have written reflects the circuit correctly or not. Could you help me with that please

Comment: In that case, if you're not allowed to simplify it at all, it's $A + (AB + (B + C') + (((B + C') D)' + D) ')$. Assuming I've got my brackets right there.